# What properties does this inequality use?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, sobolev-spaces

today I encountered an inequality like this:
$$\langle\xi\rangle = \sqrt{1+|\xi|^2}$$
$$C\|g\|_{W^{m,2}(\bf{R}^d)}\leq  \|\langle\cdot\rangle^m|{\tilde{g}}|\|_{L^{2}(\bf{R}^d)}\leq {\tilde{C}} \|g\|_{W^{m,2}(\bf{R}^d)}$$

In the paper, the author did not give the reasons. Since I do not major in Math, could anyone help me to give a simple illustration for it? It seems like Sobolev space function's property.
PS: $\tilde{g}(\xi) = \int_{\bf{R}^d} g(x)e^{-2\pi i\xi\cdot x}dx$

Comment: Sorry that please click the link to see the image....

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Thanks for your advise and I have edited it.

Comment: @ José Carlos Santos

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3263705/showing-that-u-in-hk-mathbbrn-leftrightarrow-xik-hatu-in-l2-mathb

Comment: Thanks for all your help!